# Grapping \n1 with grepl in r

Tags: r, grepl

I have a vector of strings either starting with `\n1.` or `\ntext` and I wish to filter all those starting with `\n1.`
Sample:

```
[1] "\n1. Morgenhanen matter"
[2] "\n1. Morgenstund har guld"
[3] "\nMorgensange for børn be"
```

but I can't seem to grap those sentences starting with \n1. Here's where I'm at:

```
grepl("^['\\\\']n1", df$text)
```

but it returns false for all sentences...

In the end I want to end up with something like

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
   filter(those sentences starting with \n1)
```

I'm sorry, I'm just not the best at regex in r...

Comment: Try `filter(df, grepl("^\\n1", text))`

Comment: Thank you mate!  Feel free to post it as an answer so I can accept it!

Comment: If you want to include the dot it's `"^\\n1\\."` but otherwise, what @arg0naut91 says.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  filter(df, grepl("^\\n1", text))
```

Output:

```
                       text
1   \n1. Morgenhanen matter
2 \n1. Morgenstund har guld
```

Data

```
df <- data.frame(text = c("\n1. Morgenhanen matter", 
                      "\n1. Morgenstund har guld", 
                      "\nMorgensange for børn be"))
```

Answer (score 2):

Note that the `\n` in your strings is a newline, `\x0A`, character. The `^['\\\\']n1` pattern matches a

- `^` - start of string
- `['\\\\']` - a `'` or `\` char
- `n1` - an `n1` string.

So, as you see, your pattern does not match a newline char.

You can use

```r
grep("^\\n1", df$text, value=TRUE)
```

See the [R demo](https://ideone.com/qBPUF8):

```r
text <- c( "\n1. Morgenhanen matter", "\n1. Morgenstund har guld", "\nMorgensange for børn be")
grep("^\\n1", text, value=TRUE)
```

Output:

```r
[1] "\n1. Morgenhanen matter"   "\n1. Morgenstund har guld"
```

Here, `"^\\n1"` is a `^\n1` regex pattern that matches

- `^` - start of string
- `\n` - a newline
- `1` - a `1` char.